# I have a following mongoose "User" collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, arrayobject

```
   {
    email: {
      type: String,
    },
    customer: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
        },
        mobile: {
          type: Number,
        },

        entries: [
          {
            date: {
              type: Date,
            },
            qty: {
              type: Number,
            },
            price: {
              type: Number,
            },
            amount: {
              type: Number,
            },
          },
        ],
        payment: [
          {
            date: {
              type: Date,
            },
            paymentReceived: {
              type: Number,
            },
            paymentMode: {
              type: String,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

I want to find a user by their _id, if the _id is found, then I want to add in the customer entries like price, amount etc where customer._id matches a particular customer id.

I have tried several techniques but still not able to add an entry based on customer id and user email

Comment: Hey Dinesh, you can show the code you tried. You can use findOneAndUpdate. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Comment: @raga , thanks for your reply , findOneAndUpdate won't do in my case as I wanna check two conditions and if they match then add an entry.  However I think my collection is a bit complicated, so I am gonna break it into two collections i.e. user and customer. That should solve my issue.